# SqlDependency is not working event if queues are present and query is valid

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

with the following code, my OnChange event is not raised:

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT Name, Description FROM dbo.Boms",
                    conn))
                {

                    SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dep.OnChange += dep_OnChange;

                    // Execute the command.
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // Process the DataReader.
                    }
                }
```

I googled for any possible constrains to the query, but my query seems to be ok.
The dep object is also properly created, but I tried to insert (successfully) a record inside my Boms table but I received no feedback or event.
Inside Sql Server 2012 I see a new queue everytime I launch my application.

I looked for errors into system table but all seems ok.

Any hint to understand at least where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does executing process have select permission?

Comment: @LIUFA: I didn't write that I also use this method that returns me true: 
`private bool CanRequestNotifications() { SqlClientPermission permission = new SqlClientPermission( PermissionState.Unrestricted); try { permission.Demand(); return true; } catch (System.Exception) { return false; } }`

Answer (score 1):

Read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/), [Troubleshooting Query Notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177469%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) [Troubleshooting Dialogs](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/) and [Using SQL Trace to Troubleshoot Query Notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190758%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for troubleshooting tips.

- Using profiler, monitor the [Query Notifications Event Category](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365377.aspx) to see how QN subscriptions are created and notified.
- Using profiler, monitor [Broker Event Category](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186347.aspx) to see how the notifications are delivered, specially check if delivery fails.
- Using profiler, monitor for [Audit Broker Conversation Event Class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191001.aspx) to see if notification delivery runs into security issues.

Run this to ensure the executes as sandbox context does not run into orphaned dbo sid issues:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON database::[<yourdbname>] TO [sa];
```